# Проверить ссылку на существование

Tags: android, firebase

Как проверить ссылку на существование?

```
if(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("lobby").child(name)){
        if (password == null) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("lobby").child(name)
                    .setValue(new LobbyInfo(name, null));
            return;

        } else {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("lobby").child(name)
                    .setValue(new LobbyInfo(name, password));
            return;
        }
    }
    if(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("lobby").child(name)!=null){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Это имя занято, попробуйте другое", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
```

Мне нужно сделать так: если папка с таким именем существует,то выводит "Ошибка", если не существует,то создает новую папку с данными
В данный момент у меня всегда выбивает "Это имя занято, попробуйте другое",следовательно ссылка существует,хотя её нет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так а если под дебагером посмотреть, что возвращает конкретно ваш `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("lobby").child(name)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("lobby").child(name)!=null){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Это имя занято, попробуйте другое", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
```

Здесь всегда будет true: потому как вы просто создали ссылку на Reference. 
Чтобы проверить существование этой ссылки - необходимо установить листенер.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("lobby").child(name);
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.getValue()!=null){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Это имя занято, попробуйте другое", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```